# Get AD users with a SPML request from Adaxes

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, active-directory, spml

I'm using Softerra Adaxes to manage and administrate my Active Directory (AD). It provides an enhanced web-based management environment, gives you a role-based access control model for delegating privileges, adds security with approval-based workflow, allows enforcing corporate data standards and much more.
All of this is through a SPML web service.

Now, the problem is that i want to get the detailled list of all AD users from a TalenD job using a SPML request but i don't know how to write the request.
Even in Adaxes SMPL request runner, i don't get the right one.
I've checked on the Web but the SPML framework seems to be very less documented.

**So, what is the correct SMPL request code and parameters to get all AD users?**

This is the SPML request and response for an user lookup:

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
    <spml:lookupRequest xmlns:spml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0">
      <spml:psoId ID="CN=John Doe,OU=accounting,DC=acme.com" targetID="acme.com "/>
    </spml:lookupRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<spml:lookupResponse status="spml:success" xmlns:spml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0">
  <spml:psoId ID="CN=John Doe,OU=accounting,DC=acme.com" targetID="acme.com "/>
    <spml:data>
      <attr name="CN" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core">
        <value> John Doe </value>
      </attr>
      <attr name="uid" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core">
        <value>jdoe</value>
      </attr>
      <attr name="email" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core">
        <value>jdoe@acme.com</value>
      </attr>
      <attr name="objectclass" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core">
        <value>user</value>
      </attr>
    </spml:data>
</spml:lookupResponse>
```

This is a screen of Adaxes SMPL provider
[Adaxes SPML provider sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuQCp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such possibility. Currently, Adaxes SPML Provider allows viewing only properties of the specified object. However, thank you for the pointing this out, we will consider adding the feature in future releases of Adaxes.

As a workaround, you can use [Adaxes API](https://www.adaxes.com/sdk/) to get objects based on search results. For example, you can make a custom web service for this purpose.

Also, if you have any questions regarding Adaxes, you can directly contact our Support Team using the form on our site: https://www.adaxes.com/support_request.htm.